# How can I stop Windows 7 rebooting to install updates

Tags: windows-7, updates

I have the RC of Windows 7 and I have a lot of really important stuff pen on my pc, it says it installed new updates and it needs to reboot, it lets me post-pone the reboot by 10 min - up to 4 hours but that is it,  not option to reboot when I want to, is there anyway at all to make it not reboot within the next 4 hours without manually clicking the buttons to keep extending it by 4 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Col said, stop the update service. This can also be done through the action center/ windows update method. Only check manually and when you can restart straight away.

3rd party method is this software. Does loads of stuff which may be useful but will "Disable automatic restart after Windows Updating".
http://www.winvistaclub.com/Ultimate_Windows_Tweaker.html

Edit: It's also a portable app, no need to install.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can avoid that problem altogether by disabling automatic updates and updating manually when you are ready.

Just select "Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them" in Control Panel/Windows Update. That way you will always know about new updates and (hopefully) won't forget to install them :]

Answer (score 1):

Run -> gpedit.msc -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update -> Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations

Set to enable and 1440 minutes (24 hours) and reboot whenever you have time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work on 7 but try going to a command prompt and typing net stop wuauserv

This stops the windows update service, you can achieve the same thing by doing start run services.msc finding the automatic update service and stopping it.

Comment: Does this stop the service for good, or does it only stop it for that session? If it only stops it for that session it's ok, otherwise I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Stopping is only for this boot. You would need to change the service's Startup attribute to make it permanent.