# How to stop Windows update popups?

Tags: windows-7, updates, windows-update

I'm working on the project on my Windows 7 and have 20 browser tabs and 10 other windows open and right when I'm in the middle of typing this &#^$ pops up:

[image]

and if I click away it goes away for like 10 or so minutes and then pops up again.

**Microsoft, I DO NOT want to restart my computer now!**

So my queston is -- Is there any way to make this annoying window go away without restarting my computer NOW?

Comment: Also: [How can I stop Windows 7 rebooting to install updates](http://superuser.com/questions/38195/how-can-i-stop-windows-7-rebooting-to-install-updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have Windows Update set to automatically install updates. After an update has been automatically installed, if a reboot is required, it will display this prompt.

You can open the ***"Remind me in"*** list and select "4 hours" to limit how often it reminds you to reboot, but I don't think you can totally eliminate it.

I believe if you stop the process as already suggested by Will.Beninger:

> sc stop wuauserv

that the process will at some point, be automatically restarted and you will receive the prompts again.

For me, I set Windows Update to only notify me when updates are available. I get a taskbar notification icon that appears when updates are available and I can choose what updates to apply and when to apply them. That way, I only get the Windows update popup after I have specifically initiated an update.

Comment: Thanks. You're correct. Since I run Windows 7 Ultimate, this method worked for me: Go to Start / Run / gpedit.msc (run as admin) / Local Computer Policy / Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Update / and set "Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations" to the max allowed value of 1440, which is once a day. That way it is less nagging.

Answer (score 1):

The message you are seeing is the windows update service/process popping up to remind you that Windows needs to restart the Computer. It does this because while the files are being accessed they can't be updated.

If you want to stop seeing this message then you need to `stop` the process.

Go into your command prompt and type:

> sc stop wuauserv

This will kill the process until you restart.

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Many people won't want to just type something into their system when they don't know what the results will be.

Comment: Cleaned it up and provided an explanation.

Comment: This is now a GREAT answer. +1